# In bibliography, how to print the page in my text where I cited certain paper?

Tags: bibliographies, back-referencing

How to get, for instance,

[19] S. Roth and M. J. Black. Fields of experts: A framework for learning image priors. In IEEE Conf. on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition, 2005. 1, 2, 7, 8

where the last numbers (1, 2, 7, 8) are the pages where I cited the paper in MY TEXT?

This would be like a reversed reference, or a index for bibliography.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature to which you refer is known as "back references". If you are using the `hyperref` package, you can just pass `backref=page` as a package option. If however, you are not using `hyperref` (and don't wish to), you can also `\usepackage{backref}` without `hyperref`. (You do not mention how familiar you are with LaTeX; if you have any trouble understanding how to do this, please amend your question appropriately.)

These will enable backreferences for *all* items in the bibliography. It is not quite clear from your question whether you instead only want this to apply to a single paper. If so, please clarify, and we will see if we can help.

Answer (score 3):

The [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) package also offers a `backref` option that may be used together with `hyperref`. See section 3.1.2.1 of the `biblatex` manual for the configuration of back references possible via the `backrefstyle` option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backref=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% just for the example

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]