# How to count the number of times a reference was cited?

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, counters

I used the command \ cite in my entire thesis. I cannot count the number of times that each reference appears in the thesis after being described in the Bibliographic References as shown in the Figure below. How to make?[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a complete, minimal example that replicates your current behaviour. To know what is meant by that, please read this: [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) Can you do that?

Comment: Also, there's a difference between "count the number of times something has been `\cite`d" (first element listed in the image) and "list the page numbers that the `\cite`s appear on" (second set of hyperlinked elements shown in the image). Which are you after?

Comment: @Werner Excuse me. I expressed myself badly. You are right. What I'm looking for is "list the page numbers that the \ cites appear on" (second set of hyperlinked elements shown in the image).

Comment: Very related, possible duplicates: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145997/how-to-show-the-pages-where-references-were-used-in-the-bibliography and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68876/in-bibliography-how-to-print-the-page-in-my-text-where-i-cited-certain-paper and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15971/bibliography-with-page-numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a command in LaTeX for this. Maybe counting the occurrences with grep could to the trick for you:

```
grep -c \cite{yourreference} yourthesis.tex
```

And add it (in case you want to display it in the bibliography) somehow manually to the bibliography entry.